# Dotnet MAUI App has a different view of the file store running under the debugger

Tags: c#, windows, file, maui, appdata

I have a dotNet MAUI application that creates a file in the user's AppData/Roaming directory. Running under the Visual Studio debugger, the application creates files that I can see in Windows Explorer.

But when I try to delete the files so I can perform a clean start trial, the application is reading a completely different set of files to the ones I can see in Windows Explorer.

The program will read in data from the file 'MAE5-...' despite the fact it is nowhere to be seen!

[image]

I can delete the files from the program but not via the shell.

One possibility is some sort of weird file system corruption, another is Visual Studio is running my program in some sort of virtual machine. I haven't asked for that to happen.

As described above, I tried to delete files so I could perform a fresh test and can't because somehow files in AppData/Roaming are being cached somewhere. Is there some way to flush this cache?

Comment: You can check this thread about [Roaming folder](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/all/windows-10-roaming-folder/6c99ffdc-90d5-4d1d-8ab1-b4f448ecc8ee) for more information.

Comment: It is NOT a hidden files issue. It is a 'Windows is keeping a separate view of this directory somewhere and not letting me know where' problem.

Explorer is showing me the directory and the files in it.

Comment: The keys folder is a subfolder of the mesh folder, and it contains files that store encryption keys for the Blazor WebView component. These keys are used to protect the communication between the native app and the web content hosted in the Blazor WebView component. The keys folder may contain files such as key.rsa and key.aes that store the public and private keys for encryption.